# Wordpress wp_insert_post in post type doesnt work

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I created a custom post type with [CPT](https://tr.wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) plugin. It's works fine and did the job.
**I can create post, publish the post and i can see on the site.**
But when i create a post from frontend via `wp_insert_post` it's creates the post but i can't see on site. It gives me `404`.

```
$postId = "" . getUserCompanyId() . $menuId . "";

$m = array(
    'insert_id' => intval($postId),
    'post_title' => $menuName . ' | ' . $postId,
    'post_name' => ''.$postId.'',
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'draft',
    'post_author' => get_current_user_id(),
    'post_type' => 'm',
);

$insert = wp_insert_post( $m );
```

When i create a post:
[image]

When i publish and see on site:
[image]

Note: `wp_insert_post` works just fine when change `post_type` to `post`

Comment: You made post status draft. That's why it's 404

Comment: i published. it doesnt work

Comment: Also insert_id is not valid parameter

Comment: yes i tried with `ID` as well.

Comment: Did you fix all the other problems you had in your other question.

Comment: no. I decided to use the CPT plugin.

Answer (score 0):

`insert_id` is not allowed in post arguments array(`$m` in your code) it must be `ID`.
But as you mentioned you need to **create** a post then **ID is not required** it is only needed when you wish to update an existing post.

Refer [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) for wp_insert_post(...)

Also, validate whether the post is created on not

```
$post_args = array('post_type' => 'your_custom_post',
  /*other default parameters you want to set*/
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($post_args);
if(!is_wp_error($post_id)){
  //the post is valid
} else {
  //there was an error in the post insertion, 
  echo $post_id->get_error_message();
}
```

Comment: One more thing `post_status` must be 'publish'

Comment: `$post_args = array(
    'ID' => intval($postId),
    'post_type' => 'm',
    'post_title' => $menuName . ' | ' . $postId,
    'post_name' => ''.$postId.'',
    'post_content' => '',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_author' => get_current_user_id(),
  /*other default parameters you want to set*/
);
$post_id = wp_insert_post($post_args);
if(!is_wp_error($post_id)){
  echo 'created ' . $post_id;
} else {
  //there was an error in the post insertion, 
  echo $post_id->get_error_message();
}` returns : `created 0` and it didn't crate a post.

Comment: $post_args is: `Array
(
    [ID] => 232318500838640604
    [post_type] => m
    [post_title] => test 2 | 232318500838640604
    [post_name] => 232318500838640604
    [post_content] => 
    [post_status] => publish
    [post_author] => 2
)`

Comment: ID is not required when you wish to create a new post, it is only needed for update process. Try without `ID`

Comment: okay its inserted post but it still gives me `404`

Comment: by the way, it has to be at least one character. When i try wih one character it works as fine.

Comment: There are several loopholes here: 
1. `ID` is auto-generated and it can't be that big [Database might not be able to store it] So let it auto generate
2. What permalink are you using to view the post you created? You may find it in backend or via `get_post_permalink` function. 3. You might have to update permalink: Quick way to do so -- Admin > Settings > Permalinks > click on Save

Comment: the weird part is if i create new post `m` type from wordpress admin panel it works.

Comment: 1. I dont this so it just `a790121792` (i changed and tried it). 3. I did that too many times.

Comment: You shared code with ID set to 232318500838640604

Comment: 2. says : `Warning: Attempt to read property "post_type" on null in path\domain.com\wp-includes\link-template.php on line 328`

Comment: [see](https://i.hizliresim.com/25kcw7e.jpg) and 404.php is > `<?php

pre_print(get_post_permalink("a790121792"));
?>

404`

Comment: get_post_permalink accepts only INT(integer).
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_permalink/

Comment: gives me: `http://domain.url/m/a324262835/`

Comment: gives just the url

Comment: Yeah, that is the URL you must be using to view the post you created.

Comment: yes it is. so now? any idea?

Comment: If you are still getting 404 refer: https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-wordpress-posts-returning-404-error/